# DataGridComboBoxColumn is empty

Tags: wpf, datagridcomboboxcolumn

My DataGridComboBoxColumn does not show any data. It's empty.
I have no problem to fill a ComboBox, but DataGridComboBoxColumn doesn't work. 
.NetFramework 4.6.1

Model:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class AddressViewModel
{
    public AddressViewModel()
    {
        LoadAdresses();
        LoadCountries();
    }

    public List<Address> AddressList { get; set; }
    public List<string> CountryList { get; set; }


    private void LoadAdresses()
    {
        AddressList = new List<Model.Address>();
        AddressList.Add(new Model.Address(){ Firstname = "Peter", Lastname = "R.", Country = "A" });
        AddressList.Add(new Model.Address(){ Firstname = "Tom", Lastname = "A.", Country = "A" });
        AddressList.Add(new Model.Address(){ Firstname = "Sam", Lastname = "F.", Country = "A" });
    }

    private void LoadCountries()
    {
        CountryList = new List<string>();
        CountryList.Add("A");
        CountryList.Add("D");
        CountryList.Add("CH");
        CountryList.Add("GB");
        CountryList.Add("F");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:AddressViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="AddressDataGrid" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AddressList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Firstname" Binding="{Binding Firstname}" />               
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lastname" Binding="{Binding Lastname}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Country" 
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Country}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <!--This ComboBox works-->
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}"/>
</Grid>
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding to a property `CountryList` in your `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. But this property is not in your class `Address`; it's in your class `AddressViewModel`. Thats why you don't see anything in your `ComboBox`; the binding is not valid.

Each entry in your `List<Address> AddressList` stands for one line in your `DataGrid` and you can access each property of `Address` in each line with the 'normal' binding `{Binding Property}`. But you want to access a property which is in the class that holds the `List<Address> AddressList`. That's why you have to use a different way to bind. Two ways are possible:

- `RelativeSource` binding
- binding via `ElementName`

This should work for you

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Country"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Country}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                    Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.CountryList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource"
                    Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.CountryList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

And just a hint: if you bind collections to your view use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` to keep your view up to date.

Comment: My DataGrid is bound to a instance of List<Address> AddressList. The class Address has got a property Country. The DataGridComboBoxColumn is bound to this property and uses a instance of List<string> CountryList for ItemsSource to generate the content of the combo box control.<br/>The other combo box works!

Comment: I know, I've seen your code :)
And I tried to explain why your DataGridComboBox don't work. It's because you are not in the correct DataContext. Each Row has an Address object as DataContext and there is no CountryList in your Address object. That's why it's not working. The ComboBox outside the DataGrid has a different DataContext. Have you tried my xaml code?

Comment: Thank you. Your xaml works and i understand your explanation. Quite complicated.That means, if i want to use the ItemsSource property i have to work with a StaticResource?